# In Kotlin MockK What Will Happen After unmockkAll?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

What exactly does `unmockkall` method do?

```
testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:1.12.8"


@Test
fun test1() {
    val mockEx: Example = mockk()

    every { mockEx.foo() } returns "mocked"

    unmockkAll()

    val res = mockEx.foo()
    println("res = $res")   // Returns "mocked", this works! Then what will not work after unmock?
}
```

Even after `unmockkAll` the mock object still functions as expected, I wanted to know what will not work.

The mock object will throw MockKException after `clearAllMocks` method but not after `unmockkAll` method.

Answer (score 2):

`unmockkAll` is a companion to the 'static' mocking functions that let you mock top level functions and constructors. For example, `mockkObject` lets you take a top-level singleton object and turn it into a mock. Similar top-level mocks can be created with `mockkStatic` and `mockkConstructor`.

When mocking these kinds of objects or functions, the change applies globally. Every piece of code in the application will now see that object, class or function as mocked. So it's important to be able to undo it again after the test to make sure you don't inadvertently affect other tests. The same doesn't generally apply to individual `mockk()` objects, because they can be created inside the individual test or test suite and don't exist outside of it.

Here's an example from the docs:

```kotlin
@Before
fun beforeTests() {
    mockkObject(ObjBeingMocked)
    every { ObjBeingMocked.add(1,2) } returns 55
}

@Test
fun willUseMockBehaviour() {
    assertEquals(55, ObjBeingMocked.add(1,2))
}

@After
fun afterTests() {
    unmockkAll()
}
```